# Regular Expression to Locate String With Wildcard Characters in a Non-Delimited String

Tags: java, regex

I've checked every single post that I can find on here, but can't figure this out.

I have a string which looks something like this: "ABC1234598901AC"

I'm trying to use a Regular Expression to match "5989" within the string, but I want to be able to match that string even if one of the characters is something different.

To simplify, let's say I am searching the string for "59(Random Character that's not 8)9".

Right now here is my Regular Expression: "59[^8]9" but when I use the Matcher in Java it is not matching at all.

Here's the code I'm using to test this:

```
Matcher test = Pattern.compile("59[^8]9").matcher("ABC1234598901AC");

if (test.matches())

{

System.out.println(test.start());

System.out.println(test.end());

}
```

Test.matches() is never evaluating to true.

Any help is appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Anything wrong with my answer, which actually *answers* your question (as opposed to the other response which does not)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to use `test.find()`, not `test.matches()`.

[`Matcher.matches()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#matches%28%29) requires your pattern to match the *entire* input (thus you would need to surround the pattern with `.*` for it to match), whereas [`Matcher.find()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#find%28%29) searches the input string for the first (and then subsequent) substring that matches your pattern.

Comment: Oh my, I can't believe I missed that. Thanks Mark, that fixed it! That does explain why when I added looking at the entire string it return results. I can't accept just yet, but will in 10 minutes when it allows me.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a combination of lookahead and `OR`, like this:

```
input.replaceAll(".*((?=(.989|5.89|59.9|598.))....).*", "$1");
```

This will retrieve the string "5989" from any input with any *one* digit something else, eg it will find "5989", "3989" or "5949" but not "5181".

If you don't care about retrieving the match, simply do this:

```
if (input.matches(".*(.989|5.89|59.9|598.).*")) {
    // it would be true for "5989", "3989" or "5949" but not "5181"
}
```